# python socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I have serverA, serverB and serverC and need to transfer files from serverC to serverA via serverB. So I did this:

```
import paramiko
import os
import sys
import socket

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.10.10.1', username = 'root',password = 'root')

host_serverC = '192.168.1.1'
username_serverC = 'usr_C'
password_serverC = 'pw_C'
path_serverC = '/home/serverC/log/'
file_serverC = 'file1.log'

path_serverB= '/root/'

ssh_stdin,ssh_stdout,ssh_stderr=ssh.exec_command('ls -ltr')
print ssh_stdout.readlines()


def download_files(files, dest, host, path, username, password):
    transport = paramiko.Transport(host)
    transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    for file in files:
        sftp.get(path + file, dest + file)
        sftp.close()

download_files(file_serverC, path_serverB, host_serverC, path_serverC, username_serverC, password_serverC)

ssh.close()
```

After I ran the program, I was getting:
    transport = paramiko.Transport(host)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 289, in **init** sock.connect((hostname, port))
    File "", line 1, in connect socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Comment: What's your question? Why that's happening? how to fix it?